# How to configure PIC24H for 20MHz external oscillator?

Tags: pic, oscillator, crystal

The basic addition of a 20MHz external resonator is becoming much more painful that I thought.  I've got a breadboard setup with a DIP package of a PIC24HJ128GP502.  Nothing fancy, and it has been able to blink an LED with the internal FRC for the clock.  My configuration bits are set in code as follows:

```
// General Segment code-protection configuration:
// leave code protection off,                       GSS_OFF
// disable code protection,                         GCP_OFF
// disable write protection,                        GWRP_OFF
_FGS(GSS_OFF & GCP_OFF & GWRP_OFF)

// OSCillator SELection:
// Primary oscillator (XT, HS, EC) w/ PLL           FNOSC_PRIPLL
// enable two-speed oscillator startup              IESO_ON
_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_PRIPLL & IESO_ON)


// OSCillator configuration:
//   enable clock switching but not monitoring,     FCKSM_CSECMD
//   allow the RPn pins to be continually remapped, IOL1WAY_OFF
//   leave OSC2 pin as clock pin (not digital I/O)  OSCIOFNC_OFF
//   High-Speed (10-32MHz crystal) Oscillator,      POSCMD_HS
_FOSC(FCKSM_CSECMD & IOL1WAY_OFF & OSCIOFNC_OFF & POSCMD_HS)

// WatchDog Timer configuration:
//   disable the watchdog timer,                    FWDTEN_OFF
_FWDT(FWDTEN_OFF)

// Power-On-Reset configuration:
//   map I2C pins to SDA1/SCL1,                     ALTI2C_OFF
//   use the smallest power-on-reset value of 2ms,  FPWRT_PWR2
_FPOR(ALTI2C_OFF & FPWRT_PWR2)

// Debugger configuration:
//  JTAG is enabled,                                JTAGEN_ON
//  communicate on PGC1/EMUC1 and PGD1/EMUD1,       ICS_PGD1
_FICD(JTAGEN_ON & ICS_PGD1)

int main(void) {
  // STAYS HERE FOREVER, NEVER LOCKS!
  while (!OSCCONbits.LOCK);         // wait for the PLL to lock
  ...
```

The only knobs (or places I can go wrong that I know of) are in `_FOSCSEL()` and `_FOSC()`.  I've tried nearly every iteration of those configuration bits that made any bit of sense (even just a wee bit..ok even the ones that made no sense).  I've also tried programming it in debug mode as well as release mode.

Environment: MPLab v8.88.00.00, C30 compiler

Relevant Research:
- section 39.13 on two-speed startup: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70308B.pdf
- Section 2.7 of the datasheet
- the header file in general, p24HJ128GP502.h, to find the correct macros and configuration masks.

Circuit:
3.3V power supply
the middle pin of the resonator goes to GND, the outer two pins go to OSC1 and OSC2, there is a 1MOhm resistor connecting each of the outer two pins for the 3-pin resonator (for stability)
resonator: ZTT 20.00MX
http://www.ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/zttr.pdf
http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?lang=en&keywords=ztt-20.00mx&WT.term=ztt-20.00mx&WT.mc_id=Crystals%20and%20Oscillators&WT.medium=cpc&WT.campaign=Crystals%20and%20Oscillators&WT.content=text&WT.srch=1&WT.source=google

Comment: I've wasted a week searching for a problem with an MSP430. In the end the oscillator just wasn't working. Can you check that with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Do you intend to use PLL with your external XTAL? Have you tried without the PLL?

Comment: A three pin crystal? Are you sure? Post the schematic.

Comment: Leon is onto something, it's probably either a resonator or oscillator module both of which need connecting a different way so make sure you include the part number as well.

Comment: Please post the part number and a datasheet link to your oscillator. We cannot definitely solve anything with incomplete information.

Comment: corrected language to reflect that is in fact a resonator, not an oscillator, thank you.  the resonator does indeed show a noisy square wave with a high time of about 270s on the o-scope.  i've tried two different resonators and am looking into datasheet now

Comment: i intend to operate at F_osc = 32MHz, F_cy = F_osc / 2 => 16MHz

Comment: i guess i'm not sure how to validate the oscillator.  i probed one of the outer pins and am now seeing a sinusoidal wave with a width of ~24ns

Comment: i also am no longer using the PLL.  turns out it's a small number of changes to adapt my code from expecting 16MHz to 20MHz.  i should have considered the value of the PLL earlier.  thank you, Chetan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the crystal sounding like it's actually a resonator (part number?), you also need to unlock the OSCCON register to switch clock sources. The compiler provides built in functions to do this, as described in the datasheet.

Here is an example from the datasheet of the code to switch over to Primary Oscillator with PLL (you need to check/set the divider/multiplier bits according to your frequency - this is for 20Mhz crystal and 80Mhz operating freq):

```
int main()
{
// Configure PLL prescaler, PLL postscaler, PLL divisor
PLLFBD=30; // M = 32
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0; // N1 = 2
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=2; // N2 = 4
// Initiate Clock Switch to Primary Oscillator with PLL (NOSC = 0b011)
__builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x03);
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0x01);
// Wait for Clock switch to occur
while (OSCCONbits.COSC != 0b011);
// Wait for PLL to lock
while(OSCCONbits.LOCK!=1) {};
}
```

Comment: yes, i saw this code in an example as well.  i am trying to use the automatic two-speed oscillator startup though which shouldn't require an unlocking step.  i have just tested putting the unlock macro as the first line in my main though with no result:   __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xBF);

Comment: I recall having similar issues with a dsPIC a while back. I would try the full switching code shown anyway, both with the auto two speed startup on and off. If it still doesn't work I might try it here (I think I have a PIC24 lying around somewhere) Your resonator speed seems about right if that's half the period you are measuring - 1/50ns = 20MHz. However it still may not be locking if it's noisy/jittery. A scope shot or two might be useful, both short time scale and long.

Comment: I am continuing to experiment but finally have something working.  It turns out my V_cap capacitor was not large enough (I had 0.1uF ceramic cap instead of 10uF).  I also didn't realize the internal logic level was 2.5V for this pic and not 3.3V.  Thank you, Oli

Comment: @tarabyte - ah-ha I see, that would cause issues. Glad to hear you got it working.